# Controller area network arbitration with same message id

Tags: can

I am learning Controller area network. The arbitration for bus access is done with a message identifier(as given in CAN specifications). So if two nodes tries to transmit data on the bus with same message Identifier, then who will win the arbitration or what condition will arise under this situation?
Maybe this is a silly question to ask at initial stage of my learning but if this condition arises how will the CAN bus behave.

Comment: it will fail to behave as intended (both think they have bus control and once they start transmitting their data it could be corrupted by the other) and whoever set two nodes with the same ID on the same bus should be fired.

Comment: @JonRB I'm pretty sure the bus arbitration applies to the whole frame and not just the identifier part. Bus arbitration is very low-level. Meaning that the frame with the "lowest data byte values" would win and the other frame will be sent directly after. The two senders will certainly _not_ corrupt each other's frames, CAN is CSMA/CA. Whoever thinks that two CAN nodes on the same bus cannot send the same message identifier, has not understood the very core concept of CAN identifiers and should be fired.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked here:
[Same priority for masters in a CAN network](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/225185/same-priority-for-masters-in-a-can-network?rq=1)

As previously said, the lower ID is winning the access to the bus.

In the hypothetical cases in which they are emitting at the same time, the frame is going to be corrupted as soon as one ECU write a 1 and get 0 emitted by the other ECU. The error frame is going to be sent!

Answer (score -1):

The one with the lower arbitration number will get to win.

Comment: Could you please expand this answer as to why a lower arbitration/ID number has higher priority and wins control of the CAN bus. Assume the OP does not understand the details. Single line answers offer little insight and are subject to downvotes or deletion.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP said "two nodes tries to transmit data on the bus with ***same*** message Identifier".